# Hypothetical Loop Iterator

Tags: loops, iterator, mips

Can anyone help me with my homework. I don't get this question can you explain it to me?

Take the following shorthand for a hypothetical loop iterator, that could have been in MIPS instruction set.

itr $t6, loop # if(R[rs]>0) R[rs]=R[rs]-1 PC=PC+4+BranchAddr

a ) Among the available instruction formats [R, I, J], what is the most
appropriate for itr?

b ) Implement itr using the existing MIPS instruction set.

c ) Elaborate on the reason why this instruction is not available in MIPS
instruction set on the basis of principles of computer architecture and com‐
puter organization.

Answer (score 0):

> itr $t6, loop # if(R[rs]>0) R[rs]=R[rs]-1 PC=PC+4+BranchAddr

This is an informal syntax and explanation.  The syntax is that there is an opcode (itr) that takes two operands: the first one is a register, and the second is a label.

The stuff behind the # indicates what they expect the instruction to do:  Roughly, this instruction is a conditional branch that tests if the value in register rs is > 0 — and when greater than zero, it will decrement that register, then take the branch to the target address.  If not greater than zero, then not take the branch.

This instruction might be used in a count down loop.

Let's write out the conditional branch using C code:

```
if ( rs > 0 ) {
    rs--;
    goto loop;
}
// ...else, fall thru to here...
```

(a) They then want you to say which format this would take if it were a real MIPS instruction.  You should draw a format for the instruction and then lookup at the indicated formats to see which is closest.

(b) They they want you to perform this operation using an existing MIPS sequence of instructions.  You might translate the above C into MIPS assembly.

(c) Theorize why this instruction might be difficult or opposed to the design goals of the MIPS processor (these design goals include short cycle duration and simplicity).